# Set clickable skip label to dialog. When it clicked dismiss the dialog

Tags: android

My Dialog shows CountDowntimer. I want to skip label on that dialog if it pressed dismiss the countdowntime and dialog popup. Start Next function.

`Timer_Dialog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textSize="25sp"
        />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_skipLable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="right"

    android:text="Skip"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`Javafile.java` where I write logic:

```
{
....
dialog=new Dialog(StartActivity.this);
dialog.setTitle("Exercise Starts in:");
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.timer_dialog); 
final TextView dialog_textview=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_textview);
dialog.show();
int brkTime=MainActivity.getBreackcountTime();
skipLable=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_skipLable);
        skipLable.setOnClickListener(onClickSkip);
brkTimer=new CountDownTimer(brkTime, 1000)
{
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
   {
   if(millisUntilFinished>0)
               {

                   dialog_textview.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000+" seconds");
               }
               else
                   dialog_textview.setText(0+" seconds");
           }
        public void onFinish()
        {

            dialog.dismiss();
            runTimer();   
        }
        }.start();
.....
OnClickListener onClickSkip = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {


            brkTimer.cancel();
                 dialog.dismiss();



            }
        };
```

Comment: Is `skipLable` in your `timer_dialog` layout?

Comment: its not working .it through exception nullpointer exception and unable to find onClickSkip.

Comment: Try using `skipLable=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_skipLable);
        skipLable.setOnClickListener(onClickSkip);`. I think your `skipLable` in is your `Dialog`'s layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Your giving correctly for `final TextView dialog_textview=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_textview);` as **dialog.findViewById** but not for `skipLable`

```
skipLable=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_skipLable);
```